# How to make a Python C function call to multiply 2 floats?

Tags: python

I'm practicing with making C function calls from python (2.7).

I've succeed the example which is outlined on https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html

Now I'm adjusting this example to multiply 2 floats and return the result. I've implemented the following function in my c source file.

```
static PyObject *demo_multiply(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    const float *command;
    float x;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "f", &command)) return NULL;
    x = command[0] * command[1];
    return Py_BuildValue("f", x);
}
```

And I'm calling this function in python as follows:

```
print(demo.multiply((2.0, 4.0))
```

Which results in the following output:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 12, in
>   
>       print(demo.multiply((2.0, 4.0))) TypeError: a float is required

Clearly there is some mistake in my implementation, however I can't figure out what it is as believe 
I've quite clearly followed documentation on docs.python.org. Can somebody please point out what
I'm missing here?

Comment: `f` means *one* float, not a tuple of them.

Comment: Ok. So I've tried the following adjustments: (in C source) `if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "ff", &command)) return NULL;` (in py source) `print(demo.multiply(2.0, 4.0)`. That seems to make things worse, because now I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: Ok. I've solved it! I've needed to adjust also to (C source) `float command[2]`

Comment: No, that's still wrong. You're getting undefined behavior, which might have looked right *this* time, but which definitely won't be reliable if you keep doing that.

Comment: Specifically, you need to pass in two float pointers to `PyArg_ParseTuple`, one for each `f`.

Comment: Would `PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "(f)", &command)` not work in this case ?

Comment: I've just tried it. That doesn't seem to work `TypeError: must be sequence of length 1, not 2. (python function argument is tuple, ie (2, 4))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to user user2357112 comments, I've solved the problem. I've posted the code here for people encountering a similar problem.

(C)

```
static PyObject *demo_multiply(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    float y[2];
    float x;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "ff", &(y[0]), &(y[1]))) return NULL;
    x = y[0] * y[1];
    return Py_BuildValue("f", x);
}
```

(Python)

```
print(demo.multiply(2.0, 4.0))
```